# How to install PHP modules on AWS EC2 without SSH knowledge?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-s3

Is there any way to install PHP modules on AWS without much SSH knowledge? I need to install PHP mcrypt, but I'm pretty new with SSH. I use putty for simple stuff like transferring files from server or compressing stuff, so the instructions on http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AccessingInstancesLinux.html are pretty complex for me. Or if anyone has nan easy step by step to follow for putty?

Answer (score 0):

To login to remote machine, you need to do SSH (Secure SHell for remote machine login)

To achieve you need to have SSH client your local machine and SSH server running to remote machine.

I believe in your topology, your machine is your ssh client and AWS server is SSH server

(Your machine/laptop) -> you may need to install any SSH client like putty, SecureCRT etc
If you are using linux machine then you may already have openssh already installed. 
You can try by running command : ssh -h or ssh -V

AWS server: it is already running SSH server so you don't have to do anything.

Now, you may need to run a command to on your ssh client to connect to ssh server

ssh -i [user identity file path] username@ip/host

where -i : user publickey/fingerprint file location path.

(Generally instead of normal password based authentication, it is used to do publickey based user authentication which is more secure than password)

During SSH connection, there are two authentication happens,

1) Server/host authentication -> It happens first. 
This for client to verify whether the ssh server it is going to connect is valid or trusted host or not. SSH client generally does this by verify the server/host fingerprint (publickey or identity file) supplied by SSH server during SSH connection with stored/saved list fingerprint file on local system. If SSH client doens't find fingerprint sent by SSH server then it will prompt to user whether to trust and add this fingerprint in trusted list or not. 
i.e 
The authenticity of host 'ec2-198-51-100-1.compute-1.amazonaws.com (10.254.142.33)'
can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 1f:51:ae:28:bf:89:e9:d8:1f:25:5d:37:2d:7d:b8:ca:9f:f5:f1:6f.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?

2) user/client authentication: -> Once server is authenticated in step 1, user authentication starts.

This is your client/user account authentication on SSH server. It is used to verify that whether user is allowed or not for login into the device. During SSH connection, SSH client software sends this info to SSH server and SSH server verify this. You must have this file present with you.

I hope once you follow above steps successfully, you would able to login to AWS server and then you can go ahead with your remaining task like install PHP, run some command etc.